# Vue.js build and deploy to single file

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue.js application which I created from webpack and when I build (npm run build), it creates a 'dist' folder with static/css and static/js folders respectively. I get

- app.12345.js*
- app.12345.map
- manifest.556.js*
- manifest.556.js.map
- vendor.991.js*
- vendor.991.js.map

In the index.html it produces, it only seems to be using the files marked with an asterisk (*).
My question is, is there a way to condense these 3 into one file so I only need to reference one file in my index page? Like ~/myApp.js? I've read about chunking but I can't seem to get less than the 3 files listed.

Comment: Put your webpack config file. It seems your file is not right.

Comment: I never had such issues with Rollup + [rollup-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/rollup-plugin-vue).

Comment: You can see a detailed answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508375/

Answer (score 9):

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  },
}
```

filename: vue.config.js (root folder)

Answer (score -2):

You can, but you shouldn't.

The point of this separation is to reduce load times and bandwidth usage when you make updates to the application. Infrequently changing things - Vue, libraries like Bootstrap, etc. - go in the `vendor` file, whereas frequently changing items go in the main JS file. That way, making a minor tweak in your app only requires the user to re-download the app's files (which are usually quite small, filesize-wise) and *not* all the big libraries it *uses*.

This is likely managed by the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) in your Webpack config.

Answer (score -3):

The question is : why would you wanna do this ? This is only for less codes, but if the project grows bigger, loading one file takes longer than three separated files.

Comment: So when I build without the chunking I get a single 411KB JS File (and a css file). If I leave the webpack as is, then I get the several files . The Vendor.xx.js is 390KB; app.xx.js 22KB and manifest.xxx.js 1KB.

So technically when I build, the app file at 22KB should be the only one changing based on the suggestion that its quicker to load. But with the webpack, each build generates a unique chunk id and is replaced in that XXX portion of the file name. So if I add a new field to the app.js, all 3 files change. All 3 files need to be redownloaded by the browser?

Comment: If the chunk hash is not matching , it will reload, and the same with one file situation, and what's the connection between your question and this case? If there's changing in the origin code, the browser has to redownload some files, that's why we need to make js file more separated so that webpack can track the changes more specific , instead of using one file.

Comment: I think it is a valid question. `vue init webpack-simple` merges all output into a single file. It easier to integrate into other systems if there is only 1 output file.