# How to output single build.js file for vue production build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using `vue-cli 2.9.6`, and created a vue project using `vue init webpack <project name>`.

When I call `vue run build`, it is creating a number of different js files (and names change each time...):

```
vendor.20d54e752692d648b42a.js
vendor.20d54e752692d648b42a.js.map
app.ed70f310595763347909.js
app.ed70f310595763347909.js.map
manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js
manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map
```

And also css files like this:

```
app.a670fcd1e9a699133143a2b144475068.css
app.a670fcd1e9a699133143a2b144475068.css.map
```

I would like the output to simply be 2 files:

```
build.js  { for all js }
styles.css { for all css }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: looking for something like this? https://dev.to/coolgoose/static--fixed-filenames-for-generated-vue-cli-builds-3a2l

Comment: Well I don't know how to apply that to the existing `webpack.prod.conf.js` file that I have. It is easy enough for me to remove the `.[chunkhash]` clause from the config file, however that will still generate 3 files: `vender.js`, `app.js` and `manifest.js`. How do I combine them to 1 file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. for preventing creation of vendor.js and manifest.js just remove following code from `webpack.prod.conf.js`

```
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
```

2. To prevent sourceMaps set in `config/index.js` the variable `productionSourceMap` from `true` to `false`
3. Changing name of app.js to build.js can be obtained modifying the `entry` and `output`properties in webpack.base.conf.js this way:

```
entry: {
    build: './src/main.js'
},
```

```
output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
},
```

4. Update name of the css output file updating options of `ExtractTextPlugin`in webpack.prod.conf.js to `filename: utils.assetsPath('css/styles.css'),`

Answer (score 1):

// vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if(config.plugins.has('extract-css')) {
      const extractCSSPlugin = config.plugin('extract-css')
      extractCSSPlugin && extractCSSPlugin.tap(() => [{
        filename: 'styles.css',
        chunkFilename: 'styles.css'
      }])
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: 'build.js',
      chunkFilename: 'build.js'
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  },
  filenameHashing: false
}
```